# Как спаристь данные сайта которые скрытые под кнопкой кнопки?

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Чтобы мне получить ссылку на файл (в маленьком окне) мне надо сначала просто нажать только потом появится ссылка. Как я могу спарсить ссылку на файл? Буду премного благодарен

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUIAV.jpg

Comment: Самый наверняковский вариант `selenium`. Ибо скорее всего тебе request не выдаст тех данных которые ты хочешь

Comment: спасибо! буду смотреть как с ним работать